# Округление числа в большую сторону с заданым шагом.

Tags: php

Добрый день всем. Сложилась небольшая задачка с которой самому не получается справиться подскажите пожалуйста как ее решить.

Вобщем задача следующая допустим есть переменная $sum = 12192919121921912 равная какому либо числу. И нужно это число округлить в большую сторону так что бы его можно было нацело разделить на 50000 подскажите кто знает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function my_rand($count,$subcount){
  return $subcount*round($count/$subcount);
  //return $subcount*floor($count/$subcount); //в меньшую сторону
  //return $subcount*ceil($count/$subcount); //в большую сторону
}
```

использование:

```
print(my_rand(101,50)); //выведет 100 для первого и второго варианта, 150 для третьего
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже помогло... оказалось простым решением